# change icon to custom in Files

Tags: pantheon-files

can I somehow change the icon image of a folder to a custom one ?

[image]

I want to change it for pCloud, Dropbox, etc...

Any clue ?

Comment: I don't have a solution, but you will probably need to find a way to change the icons in normal folder view (i.e. the right pane) and then the change should also propagate to your bookmarks in the left pane (or you may need to re-add the bookmarks at most).

Comment: I created a folder on my Desktop where I can also change the icon. If I check the folder in Files the default icon is shown (also if I bookmark the specific folder)

in Files itself I cannot set a custom icon

therefore I think its not supported at this moment

Comment: *How* did you created a folder on your Desktop? elementary OS doesn't have "Desktop"

Comment: I have installed "Desktop Folder" app in the appstore or I changed it in dconf editor.
I am not sure at the moment and I do not have my test VM with me.
will check and let you know 

but I can create folders on the Desktop and also change the icon of the folder without any issues.
In Files a normal folder icon will be shown.

Comment: Ok "Desktop folder" is 3rd-party app, I don't know how they handle folders, if it's the same as the rest of the system. If you used dconf and the icons still don't update then it's probably not supported (as the answer below also suggests).

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid this is not possible at the moment.  The icon displayed for files is determined by either their mime-type or, for executables, by any associated .desktop-file.  The only exception is where the folder path matches one of the GUserDirectory enumeration - i.e. Home, Documents, Music, Video etc.  This is hardcoded.  In principle additional "special directories" with custom icons could be catered for (although not straightforward, especially providing a reasonable UX). An issue has been outstanding at https://github.com/elementary/files/issues/171 for some time.